# PHP - Regex in malformed HTML

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match-all

I've always had problems using Regex and now I need to scan a piece of code that is malformed to get the contents of the **option tag**, what happens is that the web from where they are obtained, has a bad programming and the structure does not match in all its labels:

This is the regex that I have been using for other different sections and it has worked well for me, but in this it does not work as it should be, I think it's because of the line breaks or tabulations:

```
$pattern='/<td class="bgn"[ ]*colspan=1[ ]*>Padron[ ]:*<\/td>\r\n[\t]*[ ]+<td class="bg" colspan=[1|3]+>(.*)<\/td>/';
$output = preg_match_all($pattern, $Page, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
if(isset($matches[0]))
{
    $rtn[Padron] = trim(utf8_encode( preg_replace( "[\s+]"," ", ($matches[0][1]) ) ) );
}
```

And this is the piece of code that I want to scan:

```
        <td class="bgn" colspan=1>Padrones :</td>
        <td class="bg" colspan=3>
          <select name="select"  >


                    <option value="00" >Incorporado al R&eacute;gimen de Buenos Contribuyentes (Resoluci&oacute;n N&deg; 0230050132461) a partir del 01/08/2015</option>                    





            <!-- JRR - 20/09/2010 - Se añade cambio de Igor -->




        </select>
```

I've been using [PHP Live Regex](https://www.phpliveregex.com/) to do the tests but I can not capture the information I need, which is the one inside the option tag.

PS: I know this would be much simpler using PHP Simple Html, but the project was already given to me and using Regex.

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx should Work with php:

```
(?:Padron[\s\S]*?)(?:\<option[\s\S]*?>)([^<]+)
```

Demo here: [phpLive](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/pbY)

You should use `preg_match_all` and grap `Array(1)`

TheRegEx starts by the non capturing Group `'Padron'`, followed by the non capturing Group for `<option....>` and finally captures the `option` text in Array(1).

I don't think, it's very effective, but it does the job.